# listing a folder content : how to prevent user from going above the authorized directory?

Tags: php, tree, directory-listing

i'm working on a script to allow users to browse a given directory, which is not the directory this file is sitting in, but set in a variable.

```
 define('FOLDER', '../_files/');
```

Now, the rendred html allows to navigate subfolders inside that folder. I use a "dir" GET variable to tell my script which subfolder's content to display and a ".." link allowing to go upwards, using that same dir variable.

I've set a check that if $_GET['dir'] is equals to FOLDER, it should not display that ".." link. But it's easy enough to mess with that variable sitting in the url and wherever i do that, my script allows to browse above the authorized folder. Not exactly a safe situation...

So i'm thinking i should check the full local path of the authorized directory against the requested directory and if the latter is not inside the authorized one, not display the "..".

But i don't know how to do that. Any hints or pointer would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Even though the title doesn't give it away, this is basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066930/sending-variables-for-php-filesystem-functions-with-form-submission/

Comment: Yep, similar problem/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [realpath()](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

```
$foo = realpath($foo);
if (substr($foo, 0, 8) != '/my/path') {
    return false;
}
```

...or something like that.

*Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066930/sending-variables-for-php-filesystem-functions-with-form-submission/1066996#1066996), since I think this question is better.*

Comment: thanks you. $foo is the requested directory ,and /my/path/ the authorized one, right?

Answer (score 0):

or you could use regex

```
$requested = realpath($foo);
$allowedpath = '/path/to/allowed';

$regex = '/^'.addslashes($allowedpath).'\/?.*$/';

if (!preg_match($regex, $requested)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should use preg_quote() instead of addslashes().

Comment: preg_quote() won't replace my slashes since the regex start and end chars could be almost anything, but you can add it additionally to  addslashes()