# Delete everything that has been echoed

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear previously echoed items in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057986/how-to-clear-previously-echoed-items-in-php)

I have this code:

```
<?php

$var = true;
echo 'testing';

if ($var)
{
    echo 'Hey'; //The only thing that should appear.
}
?>
```

How would I do to only make "Hey" appear on the site?

Comment: By removing the line `echo 'testing'`.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible. As far as I know (and I could certainly be wrong), `echo` sends data back to the requester immediately. Alos, why are you echoing something if you don't want it shown to the client?

Comment: @inkedmn Data is not pushed to the browser until the response is sent. Clever use of buffers and/or managing `STDOUT` can be used to override output via `echo` or similar functions.

Comment: Over complicating it just do make a word appear on his page..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$var = true;
echo "testing";
if($var) {
    ob_clean();
    echo "Hey";
}
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? It may be an oversimplified example, but I use `ob_clean` occasionally to "delete" output and replace it with an error message.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Hard to tell if it's wrong if you don't know the use case. The code in the question is obviously a test. Don't punish people for answering questions. Downvote or close-vote the question instead, or give an answer that *you* think is right.

Comment: It's not our job to determine if it's right or wrong. Unless it's a severe security problem like `eval` or SQL injections, it's just not our business.

Comment: Something like this I was wanted. Thanks. And yes the code is simplified. It is an error message that will be shown.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer. Gave the OP exactly what he wanted

Answer (score 10):

Without being too complicated... You can just assign your output to a variable and overwrite it.

```
$var = true;
$output = 'testing';

if($var)
{
    $output = 'Hey';
}

echo $output;
```

Alternatively, (the more complex route), you can use buffers. Research [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) to get started learning about that.

Comment: I like this solution more than mine

Answer (score 4):

You can't, as it has been printed already.

Here is an alternative solution

```
<?php
   $var = true;
   if($var)
       echo "Hey";
   else
       echo "testing"
?>
```