# How to clear previous output and echo in php

Tags: php

ag.php

```
<?php  
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
$i=0;
while(1){
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    if (connection_aborted()){
        break;
    }

    usleep(1000000);
}
```

ajax:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhttp.readyState+" "+xhttp.status);
    if (xhttp.readyState === 3 && xhttp.status ===200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText+"\n");

    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ag.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

hi, at above code, i want to make a persistent connection with php and echo data in while block in 1 second interval and data comes browser like this;
0
01
012
0123
...
but i want echo data to browser like;
0
1
2
3
...
but couldn't achive it so i found this [[How to clear previously echoed items in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057986/how-to-clear-previously-echoed-items-in-php][1])
about my question but not exactly what i want i think.
anybody know is there any way to empty/remove previous echoed data? is it possible? help please.

Comment: are using div or not ?

Comment: viewing it in console.log

Comment: Your PHP code do what you want (except the `ob_flush()` which failed because `ob_start()` was not called). It's the Javascript  code which seems to keep the full response data, which is not surprising. Maybe resetting it to empty string (or null) after each read may work.

Comment: As you are using your asynchronous HTTP request as a pipe (your server never close the connection) you may need to manage a local buffer (in your client-side script).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `substr()`

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var lastResponse = '';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //console.log(xhttp.readyState+" "+xhttp.status);
    if (xhttp.readyState === 3 && xhttp.status ===200) {

        var currentAnswer = xhttp.responseText.substr(lastResponse.length);
        lastResponse = xhttp.responseText;
        console.log(currentAnswer+"\n");

    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ag.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [ob_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) is what you are looking for.

```
void ob_clean ( void )
```

> This function discards the contents of the output buffer.
> This function does not destroy the output buffer like `ob_end_clean()` does.
> The output buffer must be started by `ob_start()` with `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE` flag. Otherwise `ob_clean()` will not
> work.