# How to erase the previous echoed text in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to php so,
I have made a php code which is explained below

```
echo("1");
// a code that erase the previous output
echo("2);
```

Output should be:-
**First 1 should be printed then 1 should be erased then 2 should be printed.**

If this can be possible the please help.

I tried this but didn't work,

```
flush();
```

I also searched in Google, YouTube, stackoverflow but didn't work.
Output should be only like this:-
**First 1 should be printed then 1 should be erased then 2 should be printed.**

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057986/how-to-clear-previously-echoed-items-in-php

Comment: I dont see why you tagged Javascript, please dont spam tags

Comment: Is the target for this a browser page or are you running this in the PHP CLI

Comment: If your echo is a part of HTTP server response - you can not 'erase' something. You can use output buffer as described in the link in the first comment though. If it's a CLI you still cannot.. well.. erase. But you can ask terminal to go to the start of a line and replace printed out data with spaces for example. Described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
 ob_start();
 echo "1";
 ob_clean();
 echo "2";
 ob_end_flush();
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```